# how to wait for response from firebase after writing to it

Tags: java, firebase

I am writing a java application which will write the data to firebase and then will read the response of the request to verify if correct response is given.
My code for writing data is below:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("/Messages");
    DatabaseReference newPostRef = ref.push();
    newPostRef.setValueAsync("<POJO passed>");
```

Now i want to know that how to get the response after this data get pushed to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a onComplete() Handler

Here you find an example Code:

```
DatabaseReference dataRef = ref.child("data");
dataRef.setValue("I'm writing data", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    if (databaseError != null) {
      System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
    } else {
      System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
    }
  }
});
```

You can also use a lambda insteadof a CompletionListener. This makes the code more readable.

Comment: This is to wait for completion but how to get the response (which is a new node again in firebase) node from firebase.

Comment: You get the databaseReference as parameter :)

Comment: On using the above code my code is not doing anything i.e not printing anything on console , I even added CountDownlatch to await for the task to finish but it is not executing and not terminating .